# java jersey build a login/password consuming endpoint

Tags: java, jersey

I want to build a rest authentication endpoint with Jersey. I have already done it for a regular form on page:

```
 @POST @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) public Response login(
            @FormParam("basicbtoatoken") String basicbtoatoken) {
.....
}
```

But, now I need to build an api that consumer login+pass and issues a token for further communications. How to do that properly in jersey? Can I just pass login+pass in open mode like other fields and process them accordingly? Or is there any trick for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dead simple: basic auth ContainerRequestFilter. I'm sure you can find a reference implementation with some googling. If not, basic auth base 64 encodes credentials into authorization request header. Your back end credential store will be hit on every request to authenticate.

Nowadays this is typically solved via oauth2 protocol; a client gets a valid bearer token by various means. This is a short lived token added to the authorization header; encrypted with a trusted key (usually JWT) decoding it and checking basic sanity such as expiration is considered enough to authenticate. Credential store is only hit as often as you need to refresh this token (I've seen anything from 15 minutes into several hours)